# Clickable markers on PDF generated by qGis

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

I have created a map in the qGis print-composer with point-data. I would like to display the label of each specific point if a user clicks on it. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with PDF. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: I do not have an example of this. To be honest I don't even know if it is possible. I would be happy to hear any alternative solutions if you'd have any!

Comment: A web map would probably the easiest. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html There is a newer plugin called QGIS2Web, which works great.